# Learn Noise / Error in Least Squares If We Know Its Form?

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-regression, regression-analysis

Let's say I am doing linear regression and I have a data matrix $A$.  And, I know the noise $e_i$, is zero mean (and perhaps we know the distribution, too):

$$y_i = a_i^T x + e_i$$

Obviously from the data, I want to learn the parameters, $x$:

$$y=Ax$$

but, I'm wondering is there any reason that I cannot learn the noise, too, if I know it has a specific form like this?

In other words, I would create a matrix like this:

$$
\hat A=\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots  & a_{1n} & 1 & 0 & \vdots \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & \dots  & a_{2n} & 0 & 1 & \vdots \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots \\
    a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \dots  & a_{mn} & 0  & \dots  & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 1  & 1  & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and a solution vector like this

$$
\hat x
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1} \\
    x_{2} \\
    \vdots\\
    w_{1} \\
    w_{2} \\
    \vdots \\
    w_{m} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and a known vector like this:
$$
\hat y
\begin{bmatrix}
    y_{1} \\
    y_{2} \\
    \vdots\\
    y_{m} \\
    0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The last row is to ensure that the errors sum to be zero.

I am wondering if I will get much greater accuracy if I learn the regression this way? Thanks.

Comment: It would be more underdetermined as you introduce many more variables but only one new equation. What is there to stop other things than noise to sneak into your ws as the degrees of freedom grow?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but it seems to me that if noise has a "specific form", then it is no longer noise.

Comment: That being said, this is sure a fruitful approach if you can manage to find some extra cost terms a.k.a. "regularizers" describing what is allowed or disallowed to be captured by the new $w$ variables.

Comment: But we *often* assume a specific form of noise in regression (gaussian distributed, zero mean, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

In your formulation you have $n + m$ unknowns and only $m + 1$ equations, so the problem is underdetermined. There will be an entire affine subspace of solutions to the new least squares problem, and different elements of this solution space will yield wildly different predictions when exposed to new testing data.

The approach could fail in a particularly striking way if you create a problem instance where $\sum_i y_i = 0$. In this case, you could have a solution with $x_i = 0$ (for $i = 1,\ldots, n$) and $w_i = y_i$ (for $i = 1,\ldots,m$).

---

By the way, if you want to use our knowledge of the form of the noise, a natural way to do that is to use maximum likelihood estimation. In fact, this leads to the standard least squares formulation for linear regression. So the standard least squares formulation is *already* using our knowledge of the noise distribution. Here are some details:

We assume that the random variables $Y_i$ are independent and that the probability density function for $Y_i$ is
$$
p_i(y_i) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(y_i - a_i^T x)^2}{2\sigma^2}}.
$$
The probability density of observing the given values $y_1,\ldots, y_m$ for the random variables $Y_1,\ldots,Y_m$ is
$$
L(x) = \Pi_{i=1}^m p_i(y_i).
$$
We would like to select $x$ to maximize $L(x)$, but it will simplify the math to maximize $\log(L(x))$ instead:
$$
\log(L(x)) = \sum_{i=1}^m -\frac{(y_i - a_i^T x)^2}{2\sigma^2} + \text{terms that do not depend on $x$}.
$$
So, maximizing $L(x)$ is equivalent to minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^m (y_i - a_i^T x)^2$. But this is just our standard least squares problem.

Comment: the maximum likelihood is a good idea, thanks @littleO

Comment: So, I have a follow-up question @littleO.  Is there ever a case where you have a noise distribution that would drive you to use something other than least squares?  in other words, for what kind of noise distribution would least squares NOT be appropriate?  thanks!!

Comment: @Candic3 Yes, definitely, a different model of the noise leads to a different optimization problem. For example, Laplacian noise leads to minimizing the $\ell_1$-norm of the residual, using a similar argument.

Answer (score 1):

The noise has zero mean.
It doesn't mean any realization of it has zero sum (What you try to impose).

Actually if you work the problem as a Maximum Likelihood problem you could see it works according to the noise properties.